# How can I send multiple commands to a remote server using Python

Tags: python, pxssh

How can I send multiple commands to a remote server using Python? I had to learn Python for study purposes, I decided to try to automate the collection of information from the Bacula consoles. I'm trying with the following script, but I'm not having success. Could you show me where I went wrong?

```
HOST= 'server.name.com.br'

try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = HOST 
    username = 'root'
    password = 'xxxxxxx' 
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('bconsole')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    s.sendline('st')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    s.sendline('1')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt

    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
```

Output:

```
xxxx@xxx:~/scripts$ python automatizador.py
bconsole Connecting to Director backup:9101 1000
OK: backup-dir Version: 5.2.12 (12 September 2012)
Enter a period to cancel a command.
*
bconsole Connecting to Director backup:9101 1000
OK: backup-dir Version: 5.2.12 (12 September 2012)
Enter a period to cancel a command.
*
bconsole Connecting to Director backup:9101 1000
OK: backup-dir Version: 5.2.12 (12 September 2012)
Enter a period to cancel a command.
*

Traceback (most recent call last): File "automatizador.py", line 31, in <module> s.logout()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 353, in logout index = self.expect([EOF, "(?i)there are stopped jobs"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 321, in expect timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 345, in expect_list return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 107, in expect_loop return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 70, in timeout raise TIMEOUT(msg) pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
  <pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x7fd642e4e8d0> command: /usr/bin/ssh args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-q', '-l', 'root', 'backup.adm.lojasobino.com.br'] buffer (last 100 chars): 'r Version: 5.2.12 (12 September 2012)\r\n
Enter a period to cancel a command.\r\n
st\x08\x08\x1b[K1\x08\x1b[Kexit\x08\x08\x08\x08\‌​x1b[K'
  before (last 100 chars): 'r Version: 5.2.12 (12 September 2012)\r\n
Enter a period to cancel a command.\r\n
st\x08\x08\x1b[K1\x08\x1b[Kexit\x08\x08\x08\x08\‌​x1b[K'
  after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
  match: None
  match_index: None
  exitstatus: None
  flag_eof: False
  pid: 47488
  child_fd: 5
  closed: False
  timeout: 30
  delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
  logfile: None
  logfile_read: None
  logfile_send: None
  maxread: 2000
  ignorecase: False
  searchwindowsize: None
  delaybeforesend: 0.05
  delayafterclose: 0.1
  delayafterterminate: 0.1
  searcher: searcher_re:
  0: EOF
  1: re.compile("(?i)there are stopped jobs")
xxxx@xxxxx:~/scripts$
```

Comment: What result are you seeing, and what are you expecting? I'm not familiar with `pxssh`, but looking briefly I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you have. If it's helpful, you should be able to separate multiple commands with `;`, but that would potentially result in different behavior.

Comment: I formatted the output and edited the question. The blobs of text in comments aren't particularly helpful. Based on the first few lines, it looks like you successfully connected and sent the `bconsole` command. I believe the issue is that `pxssh` is not expecting to be communicating with the context of a console. If `st` and `1` are Bacula commands, I would try changing them to `echo "st"` and `echo "1"`. Or, maybe it is working, in which case I would try sending `quit` before trying to terminate so the console stops.